# Real size of LVM on Ubuntu 22 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I was extending my LVM in fresh ubuntu. I have 3 disks:
nvme - 240gb
ssd - 240gb
hdd - 1tb

I' ve added this 3 disks like always but when I'm checking size `df -h` shows:

```
tmpfs                      1,6G  2,2M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  227G   98G  118G  46% /
tmpfs                      7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1             511M  5,3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                      1,6G  4,7M  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

but in `vgs` it looks like legit

```
 VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree   
  vgubuntu   3   2   0 wz--n- 1,35t <454,98g
```

Can someone tell me why and should I be aware of lost space after 230gb ?

Comment: what about `lvs`? Its result would have an entry directly comparable to the size of the root filesystem.

Comment: Did you actually add the space to the logical volume? The output of `vgs` only indicates that you added it to the volume group.

Comment: ```lvs``` output is 


`LV     VG       Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   vgubuntu -wi-ao---- 931,53g                                                    
  swap_1 vgubuntu -wi-ao---- 976,00m`

Comment: ok problem is solved, I need to use ```lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/root``` instead of ```lvextend``` and finally do ```resize2fs``` I don't know why but it works and now there are full disk usage.